# Ability to create bean template in Spring

Tags: java, spring

Lets say I have a situation like this:

```
<bean id="sample" class="ComlicatedClass" scope="prototype">
    <property name="someProperty" value="${propertyValue}"/>
</bean>
```

I want to be able to create the bean programatically and provide value for `propertyValue` at runtime (pseudocode ahead):

```
appContext.getBean("sample", "propertyValue" => "value")
```

In a way, I want to create "bean template" rather than full defined bean. Is that possible in any way in spring?

EDIT:
The value for `propertyValue` is known at runtime! There is no way to define it as another bean.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just do

```
Sample sample  = appContext.getBean("sample");
sample.setSomeProperty(appContext.getBean("someOtherBean"));
```

Comment: still you can do it `sample.setSomeProperty(appContext.getBean(someOtherBeanId));`

Comment: This will work, but remember that Spring uses singleton scope by default, i.e. all beans are only instantiated once. Consequently, you will change the property of all references to the `Sample` bean when you call `setSomeProperty()`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [Prototype scope](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-prototype)?

> The non-singleton, prototype scope of bean deployment results in the creation of a new bean instance every time a request for that specific bean is made. That is, the bean is injected into another bean or you request it through a getBean() method call on the container. As a rule, use the prototype scope for all stateful beans and the singleton scope for stateless beans.

There is also the [@Scope](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java-specifying-bean-scope) annotation if you are using the [Java based container configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java).

Comment: I understand the prototype scope. The problem is I don't want to create `exactly` the same new instance, I want to be able to pass parameter in when new instance is created.

Comment: Well, that's the prototype part of it. You can create a prototype bean with the common parts, then you call a setter method with the specific parameter value.

Comment: Well, for this small example you are right. The problem is in real life scenario I have 7 beans that this `sample` bean depends on and I want all of them to use this parameter as well. I want to avoid creating all of those beans in code.